# The meaning of the number 69 Easter Egg

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In GTA 5 there is a large VINEWOOD sign like there where in GTA San Andreas.

On the GTA 5 version of the sign VIEWOOD, there is a graffiti with 69.

**What is the meaning of this number?**

I know its an Easter Egg of some sort, but what it means, I dont know.

Comment: if you don't know what 69 means then maybe you need to stop playing videogames for a bit :D

Comment: @Geeo Hehe I know what 69 is in that regard. Just didnt realize the meaning in-game :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a recurring joke throughout the GTA series. 69 is a sex position.

More info on the [GTA wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/69)

Comment: and a good one too